# Requesting maven artifact from nexus 3 using version range results in errors in nexus logs

Tags: maven, range, version, nexus, sonatype

We have a dependency in our pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sms.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>sms-common</artifactId>
  <version>[2.11,2.12)</version>
</dependency>
```

that uses a version range.  I am seeing warnings in our sonatype nexus 3's log files.  It appears to not like the format of the version range.  Though it's just a warning and the project builds, I wonder if something is wrong and how to fix it.

```
2017-01-19 21:39:06,187+0000 INFO  [elasticsearch[B55248D3-4BEE0259-FEC6D192-5718A085-14511A5C][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]] *SYSTEM org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata - [B55248D3-4BEE0259-FEC6D192-5718A085-14511A5C] [806a4b040b0995c7ad7d2136d6e546ae54d1fde7] update_mapping [component]
2017-01-19 21:41:30,275+0000 WARN  [qtp865098650-99] *UNKNOWN org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet - Service failure
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 37: /com/sms/configuration/sms-global/[2.11,2.12)/sms-global-[2.11,2.12).pom
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.RepositoryPath.parse(RepositoryPath.java:86) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.path(ViewServlet.java:266) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.doService(ViewServlet.java:136) [na:na]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ViewServlet.service(ViewServlet.java:117) [na:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicServletPipeline.service(DynamicServletPipeline.java:71) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:85) [org.sonatype.nexus.security:3.2.0.01]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [org.apache.shiro.core:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [org.apache.shiro.core:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [org.apache.shiro.core:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:101) [org.sonatype.nexus.security:3.2.0.01]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [org.apache.shiro.web:1.3.2]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.httpbridge.internal.ExhaustRequestFilter.doFilter(ExhaustRequestFilter.java:71) [org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-repository-httpbridge:3.2.0.01]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.sonatype.nexus.licensing.internal.LicensingRedirectFilter.doFilter(LicensingRedirectFilter.java:112) [com.sonatype.nexus.plugins.nexus-licensing-plugin:3.2.0.01]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97) [com.codahale.metrics.servlet:3.0.2]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:68) [org.sonatype.nexus.base:3.2.0.01]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.EnvironmentFilter.doFilter(EnvironmentFilter.java:102) [org.sonatype.nexus.base:3.2.0.01]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:98) [org.sonatype.nexus.base:3.2.0.01]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicFilterPipeline.dispatch(DynamicFilterPipeline.java:104) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
    at org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:73) [org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap:3.2.0.01]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668) [org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) [org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) [org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) [org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175) [com.codahale.metrics.jetty9:3.0.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242) [org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) [org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) [org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75) [org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572) [org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 37: /com/sms/configuration/sms-global/[2.11,2.12)/sms-global-[2.11,2.12).pom
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) [na:1.8.0_112]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what character is causing this, it may have nothing to do with the version range.  Can you file an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "Nexus" project for this and attach the pom file?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a bracket mismatch? The version range starts with a [ and ends with a ).

(initially I thought it was the comma, but then I figured that was a range)

Comment: We've been using version ranges [x,y) for a while but it requires maven 3.3.9 or newer.  Maven documentation shows this case in table 7.1 https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8903 I wondered if nexus somehow didn't recognize this syntax.